# Can I safely assume all (or most) "cc" supports "-Wall" on *nix systems?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cc

I want to write in Makefile like this

```
foo: foo.c
        $(CC) -o foo -Wall foo.c
```

but I'm not sure if all `cc` implementations support `-Wall`.

Comment: typically your makefile would have sections for each compiler you want to support where you'd define, say, `WARNINGS=-Wall` for gcc, `WARNINGS=/bla` for MSVC, and then the build command would be `$(CC) -o foo $(WARNINGS) foo.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the closest thing you can do to use only portable options is to restrict yourself to the POSIX C89 and C99 options. `-Wall` is not one of them. See the [Opengroup's Unix Specification for c99](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html) for options which are. And that only gives answers for unixy systems, not Microsoft.

`-Wall` was (AFAIK) introduced by GNU `gcc` and inherited by `clang` to be compatible with GNU `gcc`.

If you are not afraid to research other build tools, there are some that support multi-OS or multi-toolchain builds out of the box. I believe `scons` and `cmake` can do this.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no standard regarding the command-line interface of C compilers.

The Microsoft compiler (in Windows) for instance does not accept options starting with `-` at all, since that's not the syntax typically used with Windows programs.